# How to get Watson Assistant to capture multiple entities in context variables

Tags: ibm-watson, watson-conversation

I'm trying to create a Watson chatbot and I'm running into this issue.

I'm making chatbot that's helping people find organizations that provide food, shelter, drug treatment, etc.

I have a dialog node that asks the user what service they're looking for and storing it as a $service context variable.

This works well if the user says something like "I want food" as "food" gets stored into $service.

But say for instance a user says something like "I want food and drug treatment." I want Watson to then be able to store both of these variables as context variables.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Its quite simple.

Just use

```
"service":<?@entityname.values?>
```

It will store all the input value of this entity in service array.

Comment: Thank you for the answer @Rohit but how can than I access the multiple values in the chatbot to show it for confirmation.